# How to get user properties from Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I'm using standart snippet from [MS library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to get users and their properties from my **azure AD**. But unfortunately I found that this snippet doesn't get all properties that users have and only get their display name, fullname, surname, thats all, other properties are `null`, but I need to get all properties that users have. Im already google this question a lot and only found solution for **LDAP that does not fit for me.**

Image of JSON output of user properties:

[image: Image of JSON output of user properties]

```
[{"Properties":{},"Id":null,"Display":null,"Department":null,"GivenName":"Example","Surname":"Example","UserPrincipalName":"Example@Example.com"},{"Properties":{},"Id":null,"Display":null,"Department":null,"GivenName":"Example","Surname":"Example","UserPrincipalName":"Example@Example.com"},{"Properties":{},"Id":null,"Display":null,"Department":null,"GivenName":"Example","Surname":"Example","UserPrincipalName":"Example@Example.com"},{"Properties":{},"Id":null,"Display":null,"Department":null,"GivenName":"Example","Surname":"Example","UserPrincipalName":"Example@Example.com"},{"Properties":{},"Id":null,"Display":null,"Department":null,"GivenName":"Example","Surname":"Example","UserPrincipalName":"Example@Example.com"},{"Properties":{},"Id":null,"Display":null,"Department":null,"GivenName":"Example","Surname":"Example","UserPrincipalName":"Example@Example.com"},
```

So question is, how to get all user properties from Azure AD using C#?

My user model:

```
 public async Task<List<ResultsItem>> GetUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        List<ResultsItem> items = new List<ResultsItem>();

        // Get users.
        IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

        // Populate the view model.
        if (users?.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (User user in users)
            {

                // Filter out conference rooms.
                string displayName = user.DisplayName ?? "";
                if (!displayName.StartsWith("Conf Room"))
                {

                    // Get user properties.
                    items.Add(new ResultsItem
                    {
                        Mail = user.Mail,
                        Display = user.DisplayName,
                        Id = user.Id,
                        Department = user.Department,
                        GivenName = user.GivenName,
                        Surname = user.Surname,
                        UserPrincipalName = user.UserPrincipalName                           
                    });
                }
            }
        }
      var jsonEmployees = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items); // Convert to JSON
      return items;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the JSON as code not as image.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, I registered the AD v2.0 app and used MSAL for retrieving the access token by using the **User.Read** and **User.ReadBasic.All** scopes. Use fiddler to capture the network traces when getting users, I could get the response as follows:

[image]

As Microsoft Graph [List users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list) states as follows:

> By default, only a limited set of properties are returned ( businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName ).
>
> To return an alternative property set, you must specify the desired set of user properties using the OData `$select` query parameter. For example, to return displayName, givenName, and postalCode, you would use the add the following to your query `$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode`

For a simple way, I just use the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and access `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=Department,Mail,Display,Id,GivenName,Surname,UserPrincipleName` as follows:

[image]

When using the client library, you could use the following code:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("Department,Mail,Display,Id,GivenName,Surname,UserPrincipleName").GetAsync();
```

Details you could follow the Query options section under [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library Overview](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md).

Moreover, you need to check if there has any more records and retrieve all users via the following code snippet:

```
var userList = new List<User>();
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage pagedCollection = await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("Department,Mail,Display,Id,GivenName,Surname,UserPrincipleName").GetAsync();
if (pagedCollection != null)
{
    do
    {
        List<User> usersList = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
        foreach (var user in usersList)
        {
            userList.Add(user);
        }
        pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    } while (pagedCollection != null);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I leveraged the [Microsoft Graph Snippets Sample for ASP.NET 4.6](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) sample and registered my AD V2.0 app and replaced the `ida:AppId` and `ida:AppSecret` setting under my web.config file. It could work on my side as follows:

[image]

Using fiddler, I could capture the network trace for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` and it could correctly return the user properties. I would recommend you debug your application and check the result after invoked `await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();`, also check the properties of the `user` instance when you iterate the `users` collection.

Comment: I already tried to use `.Select` and it didnt worked. And I tried to add your code snippet, it didnt worked for me too, throw next error:  Unrecognized query argument specified `version`

Comment: I also tried to create C# request to graph api that didn't worked.

Comment: I used [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) v1.7.0. Have you tried to leverage [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) for a quick way to check your issue?

Comment: Yes MS Graph explorer returned all properties without `null`.

Comment: I did some test, you could refer to the updated part of my answer.

Comment: Are you have other properties in user profiles excepet `DisplayName ID and Mail`?

Comment: From my response, I could see the `DisplayName ID and Mail userPrincipalName surname givenName` properties have a valid value. By default, these properties `businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName` would be returned, and if the user has set the related property, it would has a value instead of null.

Comment: Try to leverage [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture your network traces, and decode the bearer token via [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), then check the `scp` property. AFAIK, the Microsoft graph explorer would acquire both `User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All` permissions. I just specific the `User.ReadBasic.All` permission.

Comment: I cant do that my code crushes with next error  **Error in /Users/GetUsers: generalException An error occurred sending the request**.

Comment: Maybe you could share your project with me and i will test it on my portal, maybe its a problem with my subscription or something else with portal.

Comment: I just used the git hub sample as I mentioned in the update section of my answer, I registered my app at [https://apps.dev.microsoft.com](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and only change the the `ida:AppId` and `ida:AppSecret` settings. Since you could leverage Microsoft graph explorer to retrieve your data as expected, I assumed that your subscription is correct. The only difference may be the scopes under your access token.

Comment: Have you tried to leverage fiddler to capture your network traces when running your mvc project? Does the network trace for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` return the correctly result? I could not think any other possible causes for this issue.

Comment: Yes i tried to leverage fiddler capture network traces but when i log in in to my MS account it throw error: Error in /Users/GetUsers: generalException An error occurred sending the request.

Comment: Do you mean what pictured on image by **scopes under access token?**

Comment: You used this [library?](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample)

Comment: Yes, I used the [Microsoft Graph Snippets Sample for ASP.NET 4.6](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) sample to test this issue.